# VS 2008 designer not installed for xaml

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xaml

there is no editor for c:......\Page1.xaml 
please make sure the application for the file type (.xaml) is installed

no idea what the issue could be.

i tried to find devenv.exe but i can't find it anywhere!! i have installed sp1. i have also completly uninstalled vs2008 and .net framework 3.5 and reinstalled it. did not solve it.

some more background: i installed it last week and it was working fine, the tried to install sql server 2008 dev edition but it wouldn't install the client tools because it didn't like something with vs 2008, so i unistalled vs 2008 and the sql server 2008 the installed without an issue. then i reinstalled vs2008 and then my problem happend!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Jose's answer, I would try the following in order.  One of them should fix the problem.

- devenv /resetSkipPkgs
- Go to Add Remove Programs and repair the Visual Studio Installation

Comment: this may have been the fix, i tried this and did a another switche devent /ResetAddin as well so maybe the combination did it or one of them did it. i do not know

Answer (score 2):

To repair your install, Run:

```
devenv.exe /setup
```

Comment: there is no switch for s/setup

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Service Pack 1 for Visual STudio? If not, do so.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the application for the file type .xaml is installed for this qustion

The best Answer is click start search "devenv /resetskippkgs" then run it it work